# Regex match the first appearance of a word

Tags: c#, regex

Sorry. I rephased the example as below, how can I match number (**1**) right after the first appearance of **mary** in the following paragraph ( all the three groups are mandatory in my case):

```
Regex.Match("Do you know 3453 **Mary** has a little lamb 1 and Mary likes dancing 2."
, @"(Do).*(Mary).*(\d)");
```

Currently It matches the second **Mary**, as a result, the third group captured **2** instead of **1**

Comment: Do you have a language in mind with which to execute this? Python, Ruby, Javascript, etc?

Comment: @joeframbach, it's in C#

Comment: What do you want exactly? Check if it appears or not? Where it appears?

Comment: @caerolus, sorry I have rephrased my question.

Comment: That's quite the rephrasing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.*?` instead of `.*`:

```
Regex.Match("Do you know **Mary** has a little lamb 1 and Mary likes dancing 2.",
  @"(Do).*?(Mary).*?(\d)");
```

`.*` matches the longest substring possible (greedy), while `.*?` matches the shortest (lazy). In your example, the first `.*` included the first `Mary` because it matches as many characters as possible.